# How to replace a ? by a é in an excel sheet

Tags: excel

I have downloaded an excel file where specific french characters such as é appear as ? (other specific characters are manageable). When i use the excel replace function to replace ? with é, all the characters of my file are changed to é. ? is generic and matches all characters.

I don't find anyway to make that possible. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.liamdelahunty.com/tips/excel_find_question_mark.php:

> Microsoft Excel uses the tilde (~) as a marker to indicate that the
>   next character is a literal. When you click Find or Replace on the
>   Edit menu to replace or search for a tilde (~), an asterisk (*), or a
>   question mark (?), you must precede the character with a tilde (~).

Search instead for `~?` to match a literal question mark.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ~? instead of ?.
See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214138).

Answer (score 0):

Try "~?".  The tilde means the following character is not to take its normal meaning.